# Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem on a $\sigma$-compact space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that given the conditions of the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) and additionally assuming the space is $\sigma$-compact, the result measure is inner regular for every measurable set.

I am having trouble using the $\sigma$-compactness, since even if I take a compact set from every subspace, a countable union doesn't have to be compact. I also tried taking an open set and then its union, and then its compliment - but it's only closed, doesn't have to be compact. Furthermore, since the measure may be infinite, I don't see a useful connection between a set's measure and it's compliment's measure.

Please only provide a hint, and not a solution.

Comment: Hint: Every $\sigma$-finite Radon measure is inner regular. This is a standard fact proved in, say Folland’s Real Analysis. Extending from sets of finite measure to sets of $\sigma$-finite measures simply use the observation that you have subsets of arbitrarily large finite measure and then can apply the result for sets of finite measure. $\sigma$-compact and the measure of compact sets is finite are enough to imply $\sigma$-finiteness.